# Audio Midi Setup iPhone greyed out and loading for forever

Tags: iphone, audio, midi

[image]
[image]

I keep on losing all my Audio Devices, connection of AirPod Pros to itunes breaks up for seconds, than it works for a second, then it breaks up again.

WTF is happening? :(

Im trapped in Audio-Hell! :D